# How to send array in real time on node js?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I'm working on crawler npm. There can be n number of URLs depending on the domain. Now, I want to send the URLs in real time. As soon as one url is updated in the array, it should fire an event and data sent to the front end.

- Res.send returns data once and then shows header set error. Once res.send is executed, other values can not be sent further however I managed to send data after every route is processed but I want to send it in real time.

Is there any way to send array in real time in node.js ? Here val is the array of URLs coming from another crawler.

Here is the code:

```
promise.then( (val) => {
var count = 0;
  let urlsarray = [];
  var element = {
    title: '',
    url: '',
    description: '',
    robots: '',
    pagesize: '',
    h1: '',
    h2: '',
    protocol: '',
    keywords: ''
  };
var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 20,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, response, done) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            var $ = response.$;
             element.title = $("title").text();
             element.url = response.options.uri;
             element.description = $("meta[name=description]").attr("content");
             element.robots = $("meta[name=robots]").attr("content");
             element.pagesize = response.body.length;
             element.h1 = $("h1").text();
             element.h2 = $("h2").text();
             element.protocol = response.options.protocol;
             element.keywords = $("meta[name=keywords]").attr("content");
             var x = urlsarray.length;
             urlsarray.push(element);
             if(val.length === urlsarray.length){
            console.log(urlsarray.length);
            return res.send(urlsarray);
          }
            }
          done();
        }
      });

      c.queue(val);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and I have used socket.io with nuxt.js.

1. I installed nuxt-socket.io plug in (If you are using vue/react/angular then you need to install according)
2. I configured socket.io as a plugin in socket.io.js file
3. Done! Now, use socket.on to listen to all the incoming messages/URLs and socket.emit to send values from the front-end to back-end. And same applies for the back-end as well.

Comment: Thanks, I used i it with nuxt.js and its working totally fine. Initially, I was using axios for sending requests and receiving response, I had to use timeout function and wait until crawler complete crawling all URLs. Now socket has made it really easy to get real time urls. Its perfect solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with realtime data, then I'd suggest you look into the websocket protocol.

[socket.io](https://socket.io/) is a great framework for sending realtime data to client or from client to server.

If you want a visual tutorial: [create a messaging app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7FnbI76Hg)